# how can I assign an object to "this."?

Tags: java

[image: code]

Im trying to assign the object to "this.theOctalNumber" but I do not know how. I tried googling but cant find any.

Comment: Please try to explain your problem in greater detail, or delete the question if the answer is trivial.

Comment: You'd better paste code directly, not just a image link.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is representing the current object of this class.

you wanted is `this.theOctalNumber`, you should add `theOctalNumber` to **class field**, not in construction.

```
OctalNumber theOctalNumber;

public NumberController() {
    this.theOctalNumber = new OctalNumber();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just say

```
class NumberController {

    private OctalNumber theOctalNumber = new OctalNumber();
```

You don't actually need a constructor to accomplish that.

The important takeaway though is that if you want to access `this.theOctalNumber`, you need to declare `theOctalNumber` as an object field.  I.e. outside any method but inside the class.

Incidentally, in Java, you generally don't need the `this.` unless you've also declared a local variable or method parameter with the same name.  The compiler will automatically fall back to the object field if neither of those is available.

There is more about this in the [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html).